# C# mostrar y filtrar csv para windows mobile CE OS 5.2

Tags: c#, csv, windows-mobile, visual-studio-2008

Necesito filtrar un archivo csv (con ruta local del dispositivo) para un Windows mobile 5.0. El csv tendrá alrededor de unas 500 líneas, en C#(visual studio 2008) del tipo:

Codigo;Descripcion;posicion;cantidad;

10000637;útiles de montaje,arreglo;6;2

10000921;kit reparación;9;20

Necesito poder mostrar todo el archivo en pantalla (datagrid o similar) y después poder hacer un filtrado por posición (del 1 al 10), una vez filtrado por posición filtrar por Código(tecleando el código) y después modificar, en los casos que sea necesario, la cantidad.

Me he encontrado muchas dificultades de compatibilidad para WMobile y visual studio 2008 por lo que os pido ayuda.

¿seria posible?

muchas gracias